# How to ensure value type when defining an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

So I am exporting this interface

```
 export interface Answer {
    file: string;
    provider: string;
   }
```

I want ensure that the following object uses an array of this type for its answer key...something like:

```
import {Answer} from ../models/answer.ts

const obj = {
   name:"blala",
   answers: Answer[]: [{"file":"dsfsfd","provider":"dsfjsn"}]
}
```

Obviously, the syntax above is incorrect...How do I fix it?  How do I ensure that the answers field is Answer[] without creating a type/interface for obj?

Comment: If obj has no type or interface it's implicitly any. So short: you can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to use an interface or type for this then you can typecast the value to Answer[]

```js
import {Answer} from ../models/answer.ts

const obj = {
   name:"blala",
   answers: <Answer[]>[{"file":"dsfsfd","provider":"dsfjsn"}]
}
```

Comment: you'll lose type safety this way

Comment: @DamianGreen Seemed to me like he just wanted to create a one off object that uses this schema. He could either type cast or use the methods in bryan60 's answers. In both cases intellisense and type checks will work. If you try to change obj.answers to another type the compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don’t want to create a reusable interface / type for this, you can type it on the fly like this:

```
const obj: {name:string, answers:Answer[]} = {

}
```

But idk why you wouldn’t want to just create a type